# Привет,у меня вопрос по поводу airdump-ng, сижу с этим уже неделю )

Tags: linux, wifi

Дело в том что,когда я перевожу свою сетевую карту в режим мониторинга и начинаю сканировать сети, командой airodump-ng,что бы увидеть wifi  ближайших соседей, то не вижу ни одной сети,таблица пустая

Answer (score 0):

Самые простые варианты это

1) адаптер не поддерживается

2) вы уже подключенны к своей сети wifi